# initialize array passed by pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, initialization

The function cannot initialize an array because `sizeof()` returns bytes of an `int pointer`
not the size the memory pointed by `myArray`.

```
 void assignArray(int *myArray)
 {
     for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(myArray); ++k)
     {
         myArray[k] = k;
     }
 }
```

Are there other problems ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting anything else?

Comment: "Other than that, how was the play Mrs. Lincoln?"

Comment: It's probably best if you fix that big problem first and after that wonder if that new fixed version has other problems.

Comment: are any of these comments useful to the OP in any way? He's stated a problem, relatively well (I understood what he meant), he obviously doesn;t know as much as you guys, but you think its ok to make fun?!? Real cool guys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see other problems.  However, you probably wanted this:

```
template<int sz>
void assignArray(int (&myArray)[sz])
{
    for(int k = 0; k < sz; ++k)
    {
        myArray[k] = k;
    }
}
```

Unless, of course, even the *compiler* doens't know how big it is at compile time.  In which case you have to pass a size explicitly.

```
void assignArray(int* myArray, size_t sz)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < sz; ++k)
    {
        myArray[k] = k;
    }
}
```

If *you* don't know the size, you have a design error.

http://codepad.org/Sj2D6uWz

Comment: But this isn't going to work if the OP is allocating the array

Comment: Darn -- beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: @Praetorian: I assumed from the above code he does.  I posted the second half of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Well no, there are no other problems. The problem you stated is the only thing stopping you from initialising the array.

Typically, this is solved by simply passing the size along with the pointer:

```
void assignArray(int* myArray, std::size_t mySize)
{
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < mySize; ++k)
        myArray[k] = k;
}
```

Note that I've used `std::size_t` for the size because that is the standard type for storing sizes (it will be 8 bytes of 64-bit machines, whereas `int` usually isn't).

In some cases, if the size is known statically, then you can use a template:

```
template <std::size_t Size>
void assignArray(int (&myArray)[Size])
{
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < Size; ++k)
        myArray[k] = k;
}
```

However, this only works with arrays, not pointers to allocated arrays.

```
int array1[1000];
int* array2 = new int[1000];
assignArray(array1); // works
assignArray(array2); // error
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of arrays you should be able to distinguish. One looks like this:

```
type name[count];
```

This array is of type `type[count]` which is a different type for each `count`. Although it is convertable to `type *`, it is different. One difference is that `sizeof(name)` gives you `count*sizeof(type)`

The other type of array looks like this:

```
type *name;
```

Which is basically just a pointer that you *could* initialize with an array for example with `malloc` or `new`. The type of this variable is `type *` and as you can see, there are no *count* informations in the type. Therefore, `sizeof(name)` gives you the size of a pointer in your computer, for example 4 or 8 bytes.

Why are these two `sizeof`s different, you ask? Because `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. Consider the following code:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
type *name = new type[n];
```

Now, when you say `sizeof(name)`, the compiler can't know the possible future value of `n`. Therefore, it can't compute `sizeof(name)` as the real size of the array. Besides, the `name` pointer might not even point to an array!

What should you do, you ask? Simple. Keep the size of the array in a variable and drag it around where ever you take the array. So in your case it would be like this:

```
void assignArray(int *myArray, int size)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
    {
        myArray[k] = k;
    }
}
```